# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$ and $\int_0^\infty xe^{-\alpha x^2} dx$ knowing $\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

As the title, question 5 in this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P52hf.jpg

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you know that
$$
 \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} \: dx=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}, \qquad \alpha>0.
$$ Then you may deduce, using an **integration by parts**, that

> $$
> \begin{align}
> I_2(\alpha):= \int_0^\infty x^2e^{-\alpha x^2} \: dx&= \left.\left(-\frac{1}{2\alpha}\right)x \times\left( e^{-\alpha x^2}\right)\right|_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2\alpha}\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} \: dx=\frac{1}{4\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}.
> \end{align}
> $$

The other integral
$$
I_1(\alpha):=\int_0^\infty xe^{-\alpha x^2} \: dx
$$ is easily deduced by a **change of variable**, setting $u=x^2$, $du=2 xdx$, you get

> $$
> \begin{align}
> I_1(\alpha)= \int_0^\infty xe^{-\alpha x^2} \: dx&=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha u} \: du=\frac12\left.\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) \times\left( e^{-\alpha u}\right)\right|_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2\alpha}.
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Thanks you very much,your calculus level is extremely high,haha

Comment: @RichardTsai You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

you might generate arbritary even powers of $x$ by just noticing that

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-\alpha x^2}=(-1)^n\partial^n_{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2}=(-1)^n
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\partial^n_{\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\alpha}}
$$

But it is not possible to generate odd powers out of the knowledge that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$!

You need another starting point like

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\alpha x^2}=\frac{-1}{2\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\partial_{x}e^{-\alpha x^2}=\frac{-1}{2\alpha}\left[e^{-\alpha x^2}\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2\alpha}
$$

The you might procced as above

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2n+1}e^{-\alpha x^2}=(-1)^n\partial^n_{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\alpha x^2}=(-1)^n\frac{1}{2}\partial^n_{\alpha}\frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Check that if you let say $u=ax^2$ then $dx=du/(2ax)$ but $x=\sqrt{(u/a)}$ substituting in the integral and simplify it reduces to $(1/(2a^{1.5})) \gamma(3/2) $and further reduces to $(1/4)(1/a^{1.5})\sqrt{\pi}$.
Or check integrals involving gamma functions.