# Result of $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2\times\exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

I would like to read a very thorough and explained calculation process for a couple of integrals. For the life of me I just can't figure out the result on my own, and no resource on the web were able to help me.

First, a small question: Is a primitive of $\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)$, $-x\times\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)$ ? If so, what's the derivative ?

Now the real question. I would like to find the result of: 
$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

And then, the result of:
$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^2\times\exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

Supposedly both are equal to $\sqrt{2\pi}$, but there's no way I can get there on my own.

Comment: For the first integral, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2

Comment: It would be really nice if you could use the searching function first.  this questions pop up nearly once a week and this annoys me a lot...

Comment: Even the second integral ? I'm not used to StackExchange and LaTeX, searching for LaTeX code didn't occur to me :)
My bad!

Comment: You found the gaussian-integral tag; searching by it would've shown how to do the first problem.

Comment: I edited the title so it speaks about the second integral. Thanks! I'll be studying answers now.

Comment: it is easy to grab anything together...:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357409/evaluating-int-0-infty-x2e-alpha-x2dx-and-int-0-infty-xe-alpha-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-x^2/2}$ has no elementary antiderivative. To compute its definite integral over the line, we perform the trick:

$$\left ( \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx \right )^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2-y^2/2} \, dx \, dy.$$

Then we convert to polar coordinates, obtaining

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2} r \, dr \, d \theta.$$

The inner integral can be done by a simple substitution; the key is that to substitute $u=r^2/2$ you need a factor of $r$, but the polar coordinate transformation "gives us" this factor of $r$. Then the outer integral is trivial (there is no dependence on $\theta$). Finally you finish by taking the square root of the result.

With the $x^2$, you integrate by parts with $u=x$ with $dv$ absorbing everything else, and then the problem reduces to the preceding integral.

And yes, this is a rather famous problem that would've been fairly easy to find on MSE and on Google. I went ahead and wrote up this answer largely so I could easily find it in my own history when this problem comes up again.

Comment: Ok, I need to learn to integrate by parts, I need to learn the double integral trick whatever it's called, and I need to learn how to convert integrals to polar coordinates.
I also need to learn the purpose of all three tools, rather than just knowing how to use them.
Sounds like I'm in for days, without guidance =)
Your reply and the comments will provide a starting point that I was lacking though, thanks!

Comment: @James Integration by parts is important. Polar coordinate integration is important. This "product of independent integrals is the double integral of the product" trick is really not that important; this is by far the most important application I have ever seen of it.

Comment: That does help setting priorities, thanks again :) I've been wondering for a while before writing this question, where was the $\pi$ from the result coming from.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** [Let](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) $~I(a)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}~dx,~$ and then evaluate $I'\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)$.