# Determining a constant in a probability density function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I know there is an easier way to solve this, but can someone point me to my error. I am losing a constant of 4 somewhere.

There is p.d.f $Ax^2 e^{-\lambda x^2}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x\leq 0$.
I have to show: $A=4\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^3}{\pi}}$

This condition has to be met, if it is a p.d.f.: $\int_0^\infty Ax^2 e^{-\lambda x^2} dx = 1$, or $A = \frac{1}{\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda x^2}}$.

First integrating by parts I obtain this result:
$\int_0^\infty Ax^2 e^{-\lambda x^2} dx \equiv \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2} dx$

Now let $I = \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2} dx $, then $I^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y^2} dx$

Using the substitution $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$
I obtain:
$-\frac{1}{2\lambda ^3} \int_0^{2\pi}\left[ e^{-\lambda r^2}\right]_0^\infty d\theta$, which evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{\lambda^3}$ or $A=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^3}{\pi}}$...

Not what I was meant to show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$ and $\int_0^\infty xe^{-\alpha x^2} dx$ knowing $\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357409/evaluating-int-0-infty-x2e-alpha-x2dx-and-int-0-infty-xe-alpha-x)

Comment: @tired: This is clearly not a duplicate, since the OP knows how to proceed, he just asks us to find a mistake in his computations. Pay more attention when you decide to close questions, because others will follow you and click "close" without really comparing the two questions. And this is how a perfectly valid question gets closed, unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex M. in my view this is clearly a duplicate, the question of how to calculate integrals of this type was asked hundreds of times on this site so i see absolutely no necessity for another one.

Comment: I am not asking how to calculate integral, I was asking where my mistake was

Comment: @tired: As I've said, the OP doesn't ask how to compute it (he already knows how), he just asks why he gets a $\frac 1 4$ factor that he *knows* shouldn't be there. Read the question carefully, the OP's comment above and the answer by M.LTA. Then please cancel your close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you made your substitution you were wrong, you better remarked that : 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda (x^2+y^2)}dxdy = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}e^{-\lambda (x^2+y^2)} dxdy$$ the integral : 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}e^{-\lambda (x^2+y^2)} dxdy$$ is precisely what you calculated with your substitution (draw the area $\left \{ \theta \in [0,2 \pi], r \ge 0\right \}$)

Still here for more details.

Comment: I don't understand where that 1/4 came from

Comment: It cames from the identity : $$\int_{- \infty} ^{0} e^{-\lambda x^2} dx = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x^2} dx$$ with the substitution $x \to -x$